# MembershipProvider and Caching (NHibernate)

Tags: c#, asp.net, nhibernate

Hey there, I have my own Membership-Provider where I open a NHibernate-Session in the constructor:

```
public class OwnMembershipProvider : MembershipProvider
{

    protected NHibernate.ISession HibSession;

    public OwnMembershipProvider ()
    {
        HibSession = NHibernateTools.OpenSession();
    }
//...
```

I figured out if I set a breakpoint into the constructor, it is called only once during application start. This gives me a headache since the same NHibernate-Session is used for each request, leading to funny things like "oh, i can't change my password" (the NHibernate-Session returns a cached user when calling `ValidateUser()`, which still contains the old password).

How can I force the framework to reconstruct the MemberShipProvider for each single request? Or how should it be done different?

Thx for any tipps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a separate session in each method sounds like a good idea. Better yet, open one session *and transaction* for each HTTP request and then commit the transaction when request ends.

Comment: yeah well, I also ended up with the same idea. I simply order a new session within the `ValidateUser()` - method.